Node.js Instances with Cronjobs: Control Flag Issue Resulting in Looping Behavior
I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js program where I have three instances running concurrently, each containing a cronjob managed by the cron library. However, intermittently, the control flag seems ineffective, leading to instances getting stuck in a loop. Here's a breakdown of my setup:

Three Node.js Instances: Each instance is running the same program, albeit separately.

Cronjobs: Each instance has a cronjob scheduled using the cron library to execute specific tasks at predefined intervals.

Control Flag: I've implemented a control flag to ensure that the cronjob execution terminates appropriately.


Despite implementing this control mechanism, I'm observing instances occasionally getting stuck in a loop, suggesting that the control flag might not be functioning as expected.
Here are some specific questions I have:

How can I ensure that the control flag effectively halts the execution of the cronjob when necessary?

Could this issue be related to how Node.js manages multiple instances concurrently?

Are there any known limitations or pitfalls when using the cron library in a multi-instance Node.js environment?


I would appreciate any insights, advice, or potential solutions to address this issue effectively. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
